What is the Index method inside of a controller?
I'm following this tutorial on how to develop unit tests using xUnit for .Net application. On this video he is developing tests on a controller and there is a method called Index inside this controller, and the way he speaks of this method makes it look like it is a common practice to have one method with that name in a controller.
Index makes me think of the Index page from websites but I don't remember hearing anything about methods called Index inside Controllers.
By the way, I am familiarized with MVC design pattern but I learned things on the go on my old job and never stopped to fully understand what I was doing.

Index is a terrible name; method names should be a verb and accurately depict what they do. As the method likely doesn't index (apply indexing to) anything, a better name should be sought. Importing irrelevancies from other domains should be avoided in our code where possible, because it increases the number of things we have to remember.. ("In UserController, the Index method gets a list of all users who work for the current company, but in CompanyController it all companies, but in AccountsController it.." ...no thanks! "GetCurrentCompanyEmployees", and "GetAllCompanies" for me please..

Index is an action that you have to write, just like any other action. What makes Index special is that it is the default action for a controller.
For instance, let's say that you have a ThingController and it has actions named Index and Stuff. To access the latter, you would have to use the URL "www.example.com/thing/stuff". To access the former, you could use the URL "www.example.com/thing/index" in the same way, but you could also use "www.example.com/thing" for the same effect. If a URL specifies a controller but not an action, the action defaults to Index. Other than that, Index is exactly like any other action.
For that reason, Index usually contains what you would consider to be the default functionality for that controller, e.g. displaying a list or search page for the corresponding entity. If there is nothing that you would consider to be default functionality, it's possible that you might choose not to include an Index action. You don't need to, but most controllers will have one.

ASP.NET MVC defines routing which maps URLs you enter in your browser (or from code) to controller action methods - and this is the default route set up for you if you don't change anything:
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
        

Now if a call comes in to your site, the ASP.NET MVC runtime needs to decide what action method on which controller to call.
/Home/About
--> calls the `HomeController`, action method `About`

/Company/Help
--> calls the `CompanyController`, action method `Help`

The Index method is just another of those action methods on your controller - it is "special" only in so far as it is often used as the default action method, in case no method to be called is specified in the route.
/Home
--> calls the `HomeController`, and picks the `Index` action method as default - since the default route defines it that way

/Company
--> calls the `CompanyController`, and picks the `Index` action method as default - since the default route defines it that way

But this is really just a convention - something that most developers will follow - but it's not a hard rule. So the Index action method really is just an action method like any other - with the exception of (most of the time) being picked by default if no method is defined.
For more details on the ASP.NET MVC routing - see this MS Learn page on it
